# Retrofit2 return null Unit in kotlin for 204 No Content response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2.0.2 to post data to server using the interface below:

```
@POST("/path/to/post")
fun postData(/*args*/): Observable<Unit>
```

And received success response from server.

```
05-09 21:20:21.770 23117 23224 D OkHttp  : --> POST https://myserver.com/api/notifications/123/markRead http/1.1
05-09 21:20:21.770 23117 23224 D OkHttp  : Content-Length: 0
05-09 21:20:21.770 23117 23224 D OkHttp  : User-Agent: MyUserAgent
05-09 21:20:21.770 23117 23224 D OkHttp  : Authorization: Bearer xxxxx
05-09 21:20:21.770 23117 23224 D OkHttp  : --> END POST (0-byte body)
05-09 21:20:22.473 23117 23224 D OkHttp  : <-- 204 No Content https://myserver.com/api/notifications/123/markRead (701ms)
```

But i got exception below, seems retrofit pass null Unit to onNext.
Is this expected behaviour?

```
05-09 21:20:22.496 23117 23117 W System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method b.d.b.k.b, parameter result
05-09 21:20:22.496 23117 23117 W System.err:    at com.myandroid.notification.dialog.c$a.a(NotificationListPresenter.kt)
05-09 21:20:22.496 23117 23117 W System.err:    at com.myandroid.notification.dialog.c$a.onNext(NotificationListPresenter.kt:57)
05-09 21:20:22.496 23117 23117 W System.err:    at e.g.b.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:139)
05-09 21:20:22.496 23117 23117 W System.err:    at e.d.a.g$2$1.onNext(OnSubscribeRedo.java:249)
05-09 21:20:22.496 23117 23117 W System.err:    at e.d.a.p$a.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:215)
05-09 21:20:22.496 23117 23117 W System.err:    at e.a.b.b$b.run(LooperScheduler.java:107)
05-09 21:20:22.496 23117 23117 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-09 21:20:22.504 23117 23117 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 21:20:22.504 23117 23117 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 21:20:22.504 23117 23117 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-09 21:20:22.504 23117 23117 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 21:20:22.504 23117 23117 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-09 21:20:22.504 23117 23117 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-09 21:20:22.504 23117 23117 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-09 21:20:22.504 23117 23117 W System.err:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instance passed into `onNext` is the (parsed) body of the response. Since the response has no body, it is `null`. Therefore, `null` is being passed.

You should be able to use

```
fun postData(/*args*/): Observable<Unit?>
```

Comment: Yes , it works. thank you.
I wonder in what condition retrofit will return non null Unit.

Comment: Probably never, `Unit` is just an object class. Also, since Retrofit does not know about `Unit` but uses `Void`, it will always return `null`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this does not work for me, because I got EOFexception from Gson when it tried to parse response.

Comment: Also RxJava 2.0+ had restriction about passing null arguments. I don't think that optional type is suitable at all.

Answer (score 6):

The right way of solving this problem is to use Completable like this:

```
@POST("/path/to/post")
fun postData(/*args*/): Completable
```

Then you can subscribe like this:

```
service.postData(/*args*/)
    .subscribe({ view.dataPostedSuccesfully() }, { handleError(it) })
```

Work like a charm for me with Retrofit 2.2.0, RxJava 2.1.0.