# How to handle 204 response in Retrofit using Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Retrofit 2.7.1 with Kotlin coroutines.

I have a Retrofit service defined as such:

```kotlin
@PUT("/users/{userId}.json")
suspend fun updateUserProfile(
        @Path("userId") userId: String,
        @Query("display_name") displayName: String) : Void
```

This call returns an **HTTP 204 No Content** response, which causes a crash in Retrofit:

```
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException: Response from com.philsoft.test.api.UserApiService.updateUserProfile was null but response body type was declared as non-null
        at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse(KotlinExtensions.kt:43)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:129)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

How do I handle a 204 response in retrofit, using coroutines, without crashing?

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116364/retrofit2-return-null-unit-in-kotlin-for-204-no-content-response

Answer (score 96, accepted):

According to this, use `Response<Unit>` in the retrofit method declaration.

[retrofit no content issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3075)

Comment: I spent almost 2 days on this issue, finally it is working fine with your solution. thank you.

Comment: This is helpful answer!

Comment: If the API can return both null or non-null values, this solution will not work.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `Response<Unit>` to handle 204 responses using `Retrofit` but when you handle like this `Retrofit` will not throw an exception for `4xx` responses or other exceptional cases.

You may deal with these cases with the following code:

```
return try {
        val result = apiCall.invoke()
        return if (result is Response<*>) {
            if (result.code() >= 400) {
                // create an error from error body and return
            } else {
                // return success result
            }
        } else {
            // directly return success result
        }
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        // create an error from throwable and return it!
    }
```

Comment: how to get message data from 205 ?

Answer (score 10):

Explaining answer of @Dmitri with the sample code:

1. In your APIInterface, call your API like this,

   ```
    @GET(AppConstants.APIEndPoints.GET_NEWS)
    suspend fun getNews(
        @Query("limit") limit: String,
    ): Response<NewsListResponseModel>
   ```

where, Response is `retrofit2.Response`

2. From where you call the API, check for the status code from the function like `apiResponse.code()`.

   ```
   val apiResponse = apiEndPointsInterface.getNews(limit)
   if (apiResponse.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        //response success
        ResultOf.Success(apiResponse.body()!!))
    } else {
        //handle your other response codes here
        ResultOf.Failure("No Data Found.", null))
    }
   ```

Comment: finally it is working fine with your solution. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Using a custom interceptor to change `204`'s to `200`'s works for me

```kotlin
class Code204Interceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)

        return if (response.code == 204) {
            response.newBuilder().code(200).build()
        } else {
            response
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this solution ok with error handling?

Answer (score 0):

After almost four years we got a new [Retrofit version (2.10.0)](https://github.com/square/retrofit/releases) which now supports the `Unit` as Response type. Right from the Changelog:

> Support using Unit as a response type. This can be used for non-body HTTP methods like HEAD or body-containing HTTP methods like GET where the body will be discarded without deserialization.

So no more `Response<Unit>` - just omit the return type.